# How to save a trained model by scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, save, pre-trained-model

I am trying to re-create the prediction of a trained model but I don't know how to save a model.
For example, I want to save the trained Gaussian processing regressor model and recreate the prediction after I trained the model.
The package I used to train model is scikit-learn.

```
kernel = DotProduct() + WhiteKernel()
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel,random_state=0)
gpr.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: Read this documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Comment: Is any of the answers shared is acceptable? If OP had found a better solution I'm (honestly) really interested to learn one.. | coz I'm exploring options beyond scikit, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56319/how-can-i-export-my-learned-classiferfunction-and-predictorfunctions/245950#245950) is an entry that I've worked with..

Answer (score 71):

You can use:

**1. [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)**

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)  

##########################
# SAVE-LOAD using pickle #
##########################
import pickle

# save
with open('model.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(clf,f)

# load
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    clf2 = pickle.load(f)

clf2.predict(X[0:1])
```

**2. [`joblib`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**

From [`scikit-learn` documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html):

> In the specific case of scikit-learn, it may be better to use joblib’s
>   replacement of pickle (dump & load), which is more efficient on
>   objects that carry large numpy arrays internally as is often the case
>   for fitted scikit-learn estimators, but can only pickle to the disk
>   and not to a string:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)  

##########################
# SAVE-LOAD using joblib #
##########################
import joblib

# save
joblib.dump(clf, "model.pkl") 

# load
clf2 = joblib.load("model.pkl")

clf2.predict(X[0:1])
```

Comment: One more thing, you can add `compress=3` while `joblib.dump` this will result in a smaller file. You can check the example [here](https://mljar.com/blog/save-load-random-forest/) the compression decreases the file size ~5 times.

Answer (score 10):

You can save and load the model using the pickle operation to serialize your machine learning algorithms and save the serialized format to a file.

```
import pickle
# save the model to disk
filename = 'gpr_model.sav'
pickle.dump(gpr, open(filename, 'wb')) 

# load the model from disk
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

Hope it helps!

[source](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/)