# Safety of HDF5 files

Tags: python, file, hdf5

Are HDF5 files safe to open or can they contain malicious scripts? The reason I am asking this is because, I want to know - if I open an h5 model using Keras from an unknown source can I trust it?

Comment: HDF5 files only contain data -- no scripts or code. Should be safe.

Comment: @kcw78 How is different from pickle files? Pickle files also store data but can introduce malicious scripts while loading.

Comment: Completely different concept. You can store nearly everything that lives in computer memory in a pickle file. You could think of it as a general memory dump to disk, like a savegame. The HDF file is more like a container of something that you have to define, like a container for 100000 integer numbers and 5000 float numbers.

Comment: @Joe Thank you! Sorry might be a bit unrelated but is there a way to load secure Sklearn models as the only way to save trained Sklearn models is by using pickle files. LMK if this question requires another question thread.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the question? Are you saying that it is only possible to save sklearn models as pickle files?

Comment: That might be the case: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/ he uses pickle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107259/how-to-save-a-trained-model-by-scikit-learn

Comment: @Joe my issue is that like Keras that saves models using HDF5, Sklearn has no safe way for untrusted individuals to provide models. (I raised this issue on SciKit Learn's Github)